# No results when querying wwv_flow_files

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.03

Why do I not see any results when I run the following query in SQL Developer?

```
select * from wwv_flow_files;
```

Yet, if I run the same query in APEX SQL Commands, I see results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because

> WWV_FLOW_FILES is view top of table WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$. From
>   WWV_FLOW_FILES
>    view you can access files only associated to your workspace.